# Window Opens and Closes Immediately

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I wrote a program in Python 2.7. It's working great in the IDLE Shell, but when I try to open it in the Python Command Line, it open and closes immediately. Like, in a split second.

Please help.

```
import socket
import time

TARGET_PROMPT = "What website do you want to find the IP address of?\n\n"

def ping():

    target = raw_input(TARGET_PROMPT)

    start = time.time()

    print("\nTrying to connect...")
    try:
        ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(target)

        end = time.time()
        connection_time = end - start

        print("Connection established.")
        print("IP address found: " + ip_address + "\n")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Connection failed.\n")


while True:
    ping()
```

Edit: I deleted and reinstalled Python, and now it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Can you please post the programme and screenshot?

Comment: @imvpn22 Okay, hold on...

Comment: @imvpn22 There we go.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @martineau Windows 10.

Comment: And how exactly are you opening it in the Python command line?

Comment: @martineau I'm simply finding the Python file in File Explorer and double-clicking on it.

Comment: Hold down shift and right click somewhere in that folder. Click "open command prompt here" then type "python your_file_name.py".

Comment: That's not opening it from the Python command line. That's running it from Explorer. Run it from the Windows command line with `python myscript.py` (or maybe `python3 myscript.py`).

Comment: @martineau I got this: 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @roganjosh Command Prompt didn't open. Windows Powershell did. And it didn't recognize the file.

Comment: you need to add c:\Python27 to your path ... you will need to google to learn how

Comment: Ok interesting, i dont know why that gave you Powershell. How did you install python and what version?

Comment: The programme is working fine.  Fix your environment variable and try again. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7) to know how to set the environment variable for python.

Comment: @roganjosh The normal way: with python.org. It's version 2.7.14. And, some of my Python files are working, and some are not.

Comment: If you use the Python installer, it should have asked you if you wanted Python added to your path. Sounds like that didn't happen for some reason. You can do it manually by editing your system environment variables and adding a path to `python.exe` to the existing `PATH` variable. I think this is done by editing your computer's "Properities".